# How to take the derivative of Matrices

Tags: matrices, regression

I was browsing the derivation of the Least Squares estimates and stumbled about this problem.
It said that:

$$E = (Y + XB)^2$$

$$\frac{dE}{dB} = -X^TY + X^TXB$$

It is to my understanding that the expansion of E would be $Y^2 + X^2B^2 - 2XYB$

and therefore $\frac{dE}{dB}$ would be $-2X^TY + X^TXB$

Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: I thought $Y$ and $B$ were both column-vectors, not matrices, in the usual least squares formulation. But I also would expect to see $(Y + XB)^T(Y + XB)$ rather than $(Y + XB)^2,$ so maybe this is a different problem? Can you post other information or a link to clarify this?

Comment: @DavidK I think you're right. I think OP meant $\|Y+XB\|^2$.. I'll edit my post to include this posibility. It would also explain the transposes which I couldn't justify otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is the incorrect expression for $E$. You're neglecting the noncommuting nature of matrices. The actual expression is

$$E = (Y+XB)(Y+XB) = Y^2 + YXB + XBY + XBXB.$$

You have to multiply the matrices from left-to-right.

---

In the event that $Y$ and $B$ are meant to be vectors and $B$ a matrix, this really should be written more as

$$E = (Y+XB)^T(Y+XB).$$

So then

$$E = (Y^T + B^T X^T)(Y + XB) = Y^T Y + Y^T XB + B^T X^TY + B^T X^T XB.$$

Comment: hmm. Would you happen to know how his derivation came about? I know it's the right answer but I can't seem to get there with the mistake that you pointed out. With your expression, dE/dB would therefore be YX + XY + 2X'XB

Comment: I would think the answer would be (after term-by-term differentiation) $$Y^T X + Y^T X + B^T(X^T X + X^T X) = 2 Y^T X + 2 B^T X^T X.$$ Of course $Y^T X = X^T Y$ so that term isn't too different (sans the negative sign).